# Are regressions with student-t errors useless?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, modeling, robust

**Please see edit.**

When you have data with heavy tails, doing a regression with student-t errors seems like an intuitive thing to do. While exploring this possibility, I ran into this paper:

Breusch, T. S., Robertson, J. C., & Welsh, A. H. (November 01, 1997). The emperor's new clothes: a critique of the multivariate t regression model. Statistica Neerlandica, 51, 3.) ([link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9574.00055/abstract), [pdf](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29304719/Papers/critique%20of%20the%20multivariate%20t%20regression%20model.pdf))

Which argues that the scale parameter and the degrees of freedom parameter are not identifiable with respect to each other in some sense and that because of this doing a regression with t errors doesn't do anything beyond what a standard linear regression does.

> Zellner (1976) proposed a regression model in which the data vector
>   (or the error vector) is represented as a realization from the
>   multivariate Student t distribution. This model has attracted
>   considerable attention because it seems to broaden the usual Gaussian
>   assumption to allow for heavier-tailed error distributions. A number
>   of results in the literature indicate that the standard inference
>   procedures for the Gaussian model remain appropriate under the broader
>   distributional assumption, leading to claims of robustness of the
>   standard methods. We show that, although mathematically the two models
>   are different, for purposes of statistical inference they are
>   indistinguishable. The empirical implications of the multivariate t
>   model are precisely the same as those of the Gaussian model. Hence the
>   suggestion of a broader distributional representation of the data is
>   spurious, and the claims of robustness are misleading. These
>   conclusions are reached from both frequentist and Bayesian
>   perspectives.

This surprises me.

I don't have the mathematical sophistication to evaluate their arguments well, so I have a couple of questions: Is it true that doing regressions with t-errors is not generally useful? If they are sometimes useful, have I missunderstood the paper or is it misleading? If they are not useful, is this a well known fact? Are there other ways to account for data with heavy tails?

**Edit**: Upon closer reading, of paragraph 3 and section 4, it looks like the paper below is not talking about what I was thinking of as a student-t regression (errors are independent univariate t distribuions). The errors are instead drawn from a single distribution and are not independent. If I understand correctly, this lack of independence is precisely what explains why you cannot estimate the scale and degrees of freedom independently.

I guess this paper provides a list of papers to avoid reading.

Comment: are you shure you are permitted to distribute the paper via dropbox. better double check.

Comment: i think laplace distribution gives you the opportunity to treat heavy tails to some degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit is correct. The results presented in the paper apply only to multivariate-t errors. If you are using independent t errors, then you are safe.

I do not think the paper is well known, but I think it is correct.

The statistical literature is full of "generalizations" which in many cases are either reparameterizations, one-to-one transformations or sometimes useless because they do not contribute significantly in generalizing some properties of the model in question.