# Linear Regression with heavy tailed noise

Tags: heavy-tailed

The model is linear $y_i = a\cdot x_i + b + e_i,~ i = 1,2,\ldots,N  $. It is given that the noise is heavy tailed. However the distribution of noise conditional on $x$ is the same for all data points. My question is that how should I model the data generating process? Should I use a Student-t distribution for the noise process? Should I use M estimator in R?
Facts:
 1. OLS is not to be used.
 2. 2. The noise distribution can depend on $x$, but is independent across samples. 
 3. conditioned on the value of $x$, noise's mean is 0.
 More clarification: the distribution of noise at $x$, i.e., $N(x)$ is a function of $x$. However for different data samples $i=1,2,\ldots,M$, the distribution of noise samples remains the same.

Comment: Is this an empirical problem (i.e. fitted model with assumptions being violated) or a theoretical (math) problem?

Comment: I am given a data set containing $x_i,y_i$ and I have to estimate $a,b$

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66173/regression-model-of-large-correlated-heavy-tailed-data   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154489/pvalues-of-glm-coefficients-and-heavy-tailed-distributed-residuals   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259772/how-to-analyze-random-variables-with-non-normal-distribution/259934#259934    http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26235/are-regressions-with-student-t-errors-useless

Answer (score -1):

You could use iterative feasible generalized least squares.

Start by setting weights for each datapoint to 1, i.e. no weighting, and use the following algorithm:

1. Fit a weighted regression model for each dataset using weights.
2. Create a single dataset combining squared residuals/errors, $e_i^2$ and their respective $x$ values.
3. Fit $e_i^2 = a\cdot x_i + b$. If the noise is zero mean, $e_i^2$ is equal to the variance of the error at $x_i$.
4. Update your weights with the squared errors prediction model
5. Go back to 1 until convergence.

Comment: For the improvement of the community, please describe negative votes.